# Huawei Safety Detect checkURL API threat return empty list even when using malicious url for testing

Tags: android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

Im trying to check if url is malicious in my app. But the output always return that the link is safe even when i put malicious link. Im developing the app using Android Studio and use both GMS and HMS library. Im running the app on my device which is Samsung and its working fine except for the problem i mention above. Help me please.
And one more thing, I've downloaded the appGallery on my phone and install hms core. But do i still need to convert gms library to hms library?
Thank you.

This is the response code.

```
 @Override
                public void onSuccess(UrlCheckResponse urlCheckResponse) {
                    

                    List<UrlCheckThreat> list = urlCheckResponse.getUrlCheckResponse();
                    if (list.isEmpty()) {
                        // No threats found.
                        testRes.setText("No threats found.");
                    } else {
                        for (UrlCheckThreat threat : list){
                            int type = threat.getUrlCheckResult();

                            if(type == UrlCheckThreat.MALWARE){
                                //threat.getUrlCheckResult();
                                testRes.setText("Malware found!");
                            }
                            else {
                                if (type == UrlCheckThreat.PHISHING)
                                    //threat.getUrlCheckResult();
                                    testRes.setText("Phishing found!");
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Malicious URLs are checked by the detection engine on the cloud side. Currently, malicious URL detection is used to detect tampering URLs, Trojan-infected URLs, and malicious app download URLs. Can you provide the URL you detect for us to analyze?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Im using the url provided by huawei itself, they provide an array of malicious url. For example, "http://wap.paokw.cn". But i also use url that i got from phishtank list, "http://freefantasybook.com/folder9/adobe-3D6/". Do i have to login to appGallery to connect to the API?

Comment: Can i confirm what was your data storage location? and which area does the Huawei ID log in to the test device belong to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the API to check list of malicious URL took time to function. The response code was functioning well and can detect the malicious URL. Thank you for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please send me the link? That way I can do research. Please note: maybe the link is totally new so it may escape detection.

For your other question: "I've downloaded the AppGallery on my phone and install hms core. But do i still need to convert gms library to hms library.".

The answer is no, you don't need to convert anything. But note: you must integrate Huawei SDK when you try to use Huawei Kit features on your GMS phone or HMS phones.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Im using the url provided by huawei itself, they provide an array of malicious url. For example, "wap.paokw.cn". But i also use url that i got from phishtank list, "freefantasybook.com/folder9/adobe-3D6".